# 8Tracks API custom element with Polymer not working

Tags: javascript, json, polymer, web-component

I'm trying to make a custom element for the 8Tracks API using Polymer, and am trying to get a user's mixes and display their covers. I'm attempting to do it as follows:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer-jsonp/polymer-jsonp.html">

<polymer-element name="eight-tracks">
    <template>

        <polymer-jsonp id="ajax" auto url="https://8tracks.com/users/1/mixes.json?api_key=MY_API_KEY?api_version=3&callback=?"></polymer-jsonp>

        <div class="instagram">
            <template id="mixes" repeat="{{item in mixes}}" index="i">
                <div id="{{item.index}}" class="item">
                    <img src="{{mixes.cover_urls.sq200}}">
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('eight-tracks', {
            ready: function () {
                this.$.mixes.model = this.mixes;
                this.$.ajax.addEventListener('polymer-response',
                        function (e) {
                            this.mixes = {mixes: e.detail.response.data};
                            this.$.mixes.model = {mixes: e.detail.response.data};
                            this.fire('eight-tracks-load', {response: e.detail.response.data});
                        }.bind(this)
                );
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

I'm trying to model it on the x-instagram and x-flickr ones with little success. I'm very new to all of this, so any guidance would be appreciated. I know that the JSON/API call is working, because I get this back in the console:

```
{
    "mix_set": {
        "pagination": {
            "current_page": 1,
            "per_page": 12,
            "offset_by": 0,
            "next_page": 2,
            "previous_page": null,
            "total_entries": 31,
            "total_pages": 3
        },
        "mixes": [
            {
                "id": 679109,
                "path": "/mixes/679109",
                "web_path": "/remi/chill-hip-hop-beats-part-2",
                "name": "Chill Hip-Hop Beats (part 2)",
                "user_id": 1,
                "published": true,
                "cover_urls": {
                    "sq56": "http://8tracks.imgix.net/i/001/067/826/68609.original-9904.jpg?fm=jpg&q=65&w=56&h=56&fit=crop",
                    "sq100": "http://8tracks.imgix.net/i/001/067/826/68609.original-9904.jpg?fm=jpg&q=65&w=100&h=100&fit=crop",
                    "sq133": "http://8tracks.imgix.net/i/001/067/826/68609.original-9904.jpg?fm=jpg&q=65&w=133&h=133&fit=crop",
                    "max133w": "http://8tracks.imgix.net/i/001/067/826/68609.original-9904.jpg?fm=jpg&q=65&w=133&fit=max",
                    "max200": "http://8tracks.imgix.net/i/001/067/826/68609.original-9904.jpg?fm=jpg&q=65&w=200&h=200&fit=max",
                    "sq250": "http://8tracks.imgix.net/i/001/067/826/68609.original-9904.jpg?fm=jpg&q=65&w=250&h=250&fit=crop",
                    "sq500": "http://8tracks.imgix.net/i/001/067/826/68609.original-9904.jpg?fm=jpg&q=65&w=500&h=500&fit=crop",
                    "max1024": "http://8tracks.imgix.net/i/001/067/826/68609.original-9904.jpg?fm=jpg&q=65&w=1024&h=1024&fit=max",
                    "original_imgix_url": "http://8tracks.imgix.net/i/001/067/826/68609.original-9904.jpg?q=65&sharp=15&vib=10&fm=jpg&fit=crop",
                    "original": "http://8tracks.imgix.net/i/001/067/826/68609.original-9904.jpg?q=65&sharp=15&vib=10&fm=jpg&fit=crop",
                    "animated": false
                },
                "description": "More beats to relax and lounge to\nSequel to http://8tracks.com/remi/laid-back-hip-hop-beats \n",
                "plays_count": 1013,
                "tag_list_cache": "hip-hip, lounge, beats, chill, smoke",
                "first_published_at": "2012-03-26T19:11:15Z",
                "first_published_at_timestamp": 1332789075,
                "likes_count": 111,
                "certification": "gold",
                "duration": 2211,
                "tracks_count": 8
            },
        ...
}
```

This continues for all the mixes, but you get the idea.

I know that I'm very likely to have screwed the  tag up, but I'm only just starting out with APIs/Web Components, so any help would be brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

One of the key features of Polymer is its data-binding and emphasis on declarative solutions to problems. In your case, you can instruct the polymer-jsonp element to place the response in a variable for you then wire it declaratively into your template.

```
<polymer-jsonp response="{{response}}" ...></polymer-jsonp>
<template repeat="{{item, index in response.mix_set.mixes}}">...</template>
```

You can then use Polymer's [declarative event mapping](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#declarative-event-mapping) to wire up your response handler (to fire the `eight-tracks-loaded` event for any external listeners that may want to know).

```
<polymer-jsonp on-polymer-response="{{onResponse}}" ...></polymer-jsonp>
<script>
    Polymer('eight-tracks', {
        ...
        onResponse: function(e) {
            this.fire('eight-tracks-load', {response: e.detail.response});
        }
    });
</script>
```

[Here's a working jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vititumo/3/edit?html,js,output) with a hard-coded response to show that it works, and [here's one without the hard-coded response](http://jsbin.com/vititumo/5/edit?html,output) that should work for you if you plug in your API key (although you probably don't want that on jsbin :-)

Comment: I don't think the second example will work. 
You have to set `this.response = e.detai.response.data` in the  `onResponse` callback. Firing an event won't activate data-binding AFAIK

Comment: The `eight-tracks-load` event is for any external parties who many want to know that the 8-tracks have loaded. It's completely optional for this example. `this.response` doesn't get set there. It gets set by `polymer-jsonp` because I set its `response` attribute to `{{response}}`.

Comment: Ah ok, I missed that part. But shouldn't you then access `response.data.mix_set` in the template  instead of `response.mix_set` ?

Comment: Good point. I guess it all depends on what exactly the response looks like. From his copy-paste, it doesn't look like there is a `data` property in the response, but his code seems to assume so.

Comment: Hey CletusW, thanks for your help! I've done the following: http://jsbin.com/matevore/2/edit , but get an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : " in the JS console?